# Federating multiple ArcGIS servers with Portal for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-portal

has anyone experience with a federation of two or more ArcGIS Servers with Portal for ArcGIS?

If we try federate the second AGS, we have a problem with publishing map services in the form of web-map application (we can not find this services in Portal for ArcGIS).

I suppose that I'm doing something wrong.

Is there more detailed **documentation** how to federate next ArcGIS Server?

Comment: What is the specific issue you're having, does the server show up on your admin page under servers? The federation pattern is exactly the same from machine to machine. The biggest issue is if you're trying to use the same web adapter for more than 1 machine. Each instance of ArcGIS Server should have it's own Web Adapter. Further, Portal and your ArcGIS Servers should have different Web Adapters as well. Maybe sketch up a pic of your architecture (leaving the specific names out for security reasons)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/95163)

Answer (score 2):

Best bet is to follow [the documentation](http://server.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/linux/federate-an-arcgis-server-site-with-your-portal.htm) on federating an ArcGIS Server site (which can be comprised of multiple GIS Server nodes), as these provide more detail.

Here is the high level workflow.  Below screenshot is from Portal for ArcGIS Administrator settings, and the Portal has already been federated against one ArcGIS Site.

[image]

To add another site:

1. Hit Servers tab
2. Add an ArcGIS Server Site.  Point to the REST services URL, the Admin URL, and provide a username and password of the primary site administrator (default username is siteadmin).
3. Choose which ArcGIS Server Site will be [the hosting server](http://server.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/linux/configure-hosting-server-for-portal.htm).

You should now see the services from the second ArcGIS Server Site appear as new items in your Portal.

Typically you have one server setup as a hosting server - this requires you to also make use of the ArcGIS Data Store.  This opens up a lot of benefits (e,g, analysis services) to your WebGIS.  But you may want to federate more stand-alone ArcGIS Sites.  The following graphic shows two federated servers, one setup to be a hosting server, one just federated. Both publishing workflows automatically create a corresponding item in the portal.  Delete the item, the service also gets deleted.

[image]